# AudioRecord lockup when display rotates

Tags: android, multithreading, audio, audio-recording

I am using this for some signal processing. It all works fine except when the screen goes off and the display was rotated at the time. Normally screen off just produces an Activity onPause(), but when the screen is rotated it goes: onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy(), onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), onPause(). Ie it appears that Android 'unrotates' the screen first.

Unfortunately this seems to make AudioRecord crash or freeze in some unknown way.

The basic way I have it all operating is that in the onResume() a new thread is started and this instantiates an AudioRecord instance, sets it up, starts recording and then sits in a loop:

```
keepProcessing = true;

while (keepProcessing)
    //  read a block of data and process
```

In the onPause() in the UI thread keepProcessing (a volatile variable) is cleared, and it then waits for the worker thread to stop.

```
if (thread.isAlive()) {
    keepProcessing = false;
    thread.join();
}

thread = null;
```

When the other thread drops out of the keepProcessing loop it stops recording, releases the AudioRecord resources, drops the AudioRecord instance and terminates.

As a general start / stop mechanism this all works fine. Checking with breakpoints and adb everything seems to happen in the right order. It just doesn't work in this screen rotated scenario. I can only think it is because of the very rapid new Activity onCreate() etc after everything stops in the old Activity. Ie there is something in the AudioRecord that is still busy. What happens is everything freezes up when one tries to turn the screen on again.

If I dummy the AudioRecord code so that it doesn't actually start recording, the loop just sits and sleeps, and then doesn't stop recording again, it is all OK. It only goes wrong once the recorder has gone into recording mode.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can see that, and I've just found what was happening, which was sort of that.

Owing to an error where the keepProcessing flag was initialised, there was a race condition that could leave the background thread running when the Activity stopped.

> "If you have background threads doing work [when the activity stops], this totally screws you over"

You are dead right. It does.

Answer (score 2):

When you rotate the device, your activity is actually stopped and destroyed.  If you have background threads doing work, this totally screws you over.  The best way to fix it is to tell Android not to do that, by adding  `android:configChange="orientation"` to your manifest for that activity.  Yeah, it's a bad architectural decision by Google and annoying to the point where I almost suggest adding that for all activities.